# Confusion over Bifurcation Diagram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I have the function $f(x,a) = \frac{2}{x} + 0.75x + a$ and want to create  a bifurcation diagram of this function as $a$ varies.

An $\textit{equilibrium}$ point (I thought) of the trajectory made by the function is a point $x_{*}$ such that $f(x_{*}) = x_{*}$. A bifurcation diagram plots equilibrium points on the $y$-axis with $a$ varying as the $x$-axis.

1. Why does [this](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~shipman/47/volume3b2011/M640_MunozAlicea.pdf) refer to roots of $f$ as equilibrium points? Am I supposed to be looking for points s.t. $f(x_*)=x_*$ or am I supposed to for points like in that pdf?
2. Can someone me analyze this function so I can better understand how a bifurcation diagram works?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm guessing $f(x;a)$ is the RHS of an ODE, and you are looking for equilibrium points of
$$
\frac{d x}{d t} = f(x;a).
$$

If this is the case, then such points, $x_*$, are given by the relation
$$
\frac{2}{x_*} +\frac{x_*}{4} = -a,
$$

which translates to
$$
x_*^2 + 4 a x_* + 8 = 0.
$$

What remains is to analyze this equation as $a$ varies (i.e., number of solutions and value), and construct the diagram by plotting $x_*$ as function of $a$. Note that there are values of $a$ where there are two real solutions, a critical value where there is only one, and values where there is none. All of this should be reflected in your diagram.

Comment: Why do you say equil points are given by the relation $\frac{2}{x_{*}} + \frac{x_{*}}{4} = -a$? Shouldn't they be points $x_*$ that satisfy $$\frac{2}{x} + \frac{x_*}{4} + a = x_*$$ ?

Comment: @bifurcationLost What's the difference between the two equations exactly?

Comment: @bifurcationLost One looks for bifurcation on families of solutions. The question is, solutions of what?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Ah, nothing other than me reading too quickly. My mistake entirely.